# Entity Framework Database connection error on high usage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, unit-of-work

We have an application running on ASP.NET MVC 3 using Entity Framework 4.0 `unitofwork` pattern.

The application runs fine when there is normal load on the system. We simulated some load using jmeter (20 concurrent users). While this was running, we got the following exception

```
 Error: System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

What can I do so that there are no ms sql exception under a high usage environment?

Comment: The usual suspect: multiple threads addressing one context instance. Use context per request.